# Internal storage path

Tags: java, android

I have this Code to store a Picture:

```
 imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"fname_" + ".jpg"));
                intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

it stores the Picture in 
/file:/storage/emulated/0/fname_.jpg

Then I would like to Show the Picture in imageView

```
  Log.d("URI",imageUri.toString());
        File imgFile = new  File(imageUri.toString());

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());



        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

But It says:

E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/emulated/0/fname_.jpg (No such file or directory)

I can See the Picture in Interer Speicher/fname_.jpg

Can soebody tell me the real path?

Comment: Where are you using `Interer Speicher/` in the code?

Comment: Does your app request the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, including requesting it at runtime? Also, bear in mind that your code will crash on Android 7.0+ due to your use of `file` `Uri` values. Please use `FileProvider`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/Camera/FileProvider. Then, you can just use [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) instead of [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html), which will help with Android Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that imageUri.toString() does not return the path of your file in the SD Card,
You could try to change your Code like this :

```
File imageFile = new 
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"fname_" 
+ ".jpg");
mSavedPath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
          intent.putExtra(
android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 
CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then later :

```
File imgFile = new  File(mSavedPath);
....
```